# How to diagnose a "Error: Transaction has been reverted by the EVM"?

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-debugging, revert-opcode, require

This the error intercepted from my javascript, using web3.js

```
Error: Transaction has been reverted by the EVM:
    {
    "blockHash": "0xba0e277e390d8a455cf3634f6fe38fd1a0fb0c4dc673fdf2e383a12beb8237db",
    "blockNumber": 5838119,
    "contractAddress": null,
    "cumulativeGasUsed": 79499,
    "from": "0x8d8d315a5b1bb25e8c0b1566726454fcc11b3647",
    "gasUsed": 35463,
    "logs": [],
    "logsBloom": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "status": false,
    "to": "0x6474d5b92127ef04f30dac3f48626334d36ab489",
    "transactionHash": "0x5b36d00330a2603450fc076ed74ff96c28a5003f14641589bc8cf77f2dde6455",
    "transactionIndex": 2
}
at Object.TransactionError (C:\progetti\nterilizer\node_modules\web3-core-helpers\src\errors.js:63:21)
at Object.TransactionRevertedWithoutReasonError (C:\progetti\nterilizer\node_modules\web3-core-helpers\src\errors.js:75:21)
at C:\progetti\nterilizer\node_modules\web3-core-method\src\index.js:448:48
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)

receipt:
{ 
    blockHash:
    '0xba0e277e390d8a455cf3634f6fe38fd1a0fb0c4dc673fdf2e383a12beb8237db',
    blockNumber: 5838119,
    contractAddress: null,
    cumulativeGasUsed: 79499,
    from: '0x8d8d315a5b1bb25e8c0b1566726454fcc11b3647',
    gasUsed: 35463,
    logs: [],
    logsBloom:
    '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    status: false,
    to: '0x6474d5b92127ef04f30dac3f48626334d36ab489',
    transactionHash:
    '0x5b36d00330a2603450fc076ed74ff96c28a5003f14641589bc8cf77f2dde6455',
    transactionIndex: 2 
}
```

This is the test contract I am trying to execute

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.0 <0.6.0;

contract test013 {

    // These will be assigned at the construction
    // phase, where `msg.sender` is the account
    // creating this contract.
    address public owner = msg.sender;

    // record id => json
    mapping (uint256 => string ) private storedData;

    modifier isOwner() {    
        require(owner == msg.sender);
        _;
    }

    modifier dataNotStored(uint256 _index) {
        require( keccak256(abi.encodePacked(storedData[_index])) == keccak256(abi.encodePacked('')) );
        _;
    }

    function set(uint _index, string calldata _data_to_store) external dataNotStored(_index) {
        storedData[_index] = _data_to_store;
    }

    function forceSet(uint _index, string calldata _data_to_store) isOwner external {
        storedData[_index] = _data_to_store;
    }

    function get(uint _index) public view returns (string memory) {
        return storedData[_index];
    }
}
```

The failing function call is the `set`.

I am use that with the data I sent I am NOT hitting an already used mapping id.

> It's mandatory for me to do not overwrite an entry to ensure data is writable once.

I have the dubt that I cannot send more than one transaction at time....  could it be the case?

Comment: What parameters are you providing to set? What transactions have you already submitted? In remix this seems to be working as you are intending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After deconstruction both contract and js code, I ended discovering that I was sending a signedTransaction using web3.js using the 'gasLimit' in decimal instead of hex.

Comment: In my case I didn't have to use hex, but I did have to set gasLimit. When declaring a contract I added `gasLimit: 500000` inside the object of parameters such as "{from: wallet}" in the contract initialization and things worked out for me.

Answer (score 2):

Based on

> The failing function call is the set

Two suspects:

**Suspect ONE**

```
require( keccak256(abi.encodePacked(storedData[_index])) == keccak256(abi.encodePacked('')) );
```

If I read that correctly, the requirement is the `storedData == ''`, so possibly that isn't the case.

**Suspect TWO**

```
require(owner == msg.sender);
```

Check `owner()` and make sure that is your `{from: <address>}` when you call the function. `0x8d8d315a5b1bb25e8c0b1566726454fcc11b3647`

**RECOMMENDATION**

This is very ambiguous:

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.0 <0.6.0;
```

Use a recent compiler and set that to the compiler you are actually using. A newer compiler let's you insert a revert reason that will help with debugging.

e.g.

```
require(false, "This message will output on the console if your client supports it.);"
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: About "Use a recent compiler", In official doc I can see `pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.7.0;`. Is it anyway a bad practice?